# Yii custom Widget, loader error

Tags: php, class, widget, yii, redeclare

Please, help me with this problem (I am using Yii, Xampp on a Windows localhost):

So... I've created a new widget in "protected\components\views\Magus.php".

```
 <?php
   class Magus extends CWidget {

   //////////////////////////////
  public function run()
  {
    echo '<p style="color:blue; ">Trallala :) !</p>'; // do something.
  }
    //////////////////////////////

 } //end class
```

It's used here ("protected/views/layouts/main.php"):

```
 <?php
   $this->widget('/views/Magus');
 ?>
```

And this causes a loader (?) error:

```
Fatal error: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: 
Cannot redeclare class magus in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\YiiBase.php on line 421
```

But the error doesn't happen, if the widget file is placed directly in "protected\components". What is the reason of that error and how to correct it ? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use wrong paths.
I suggest you to put your widget php file into `protected/components/Magus.php` and then you can call it from view with

```
$this->widget('application.components.Magus');
```

Or you can keep it in folder where you have it and call it like this:

```
$this->widget('application.components.views.Magus');
```

Comment: Thank you for your very precise answer Johnatan ! I was aware (sort of) of the more elaborate way of defining loading paths, yet still hoping for a shortcut not requiring the "application.components" part.

Comment: If you are auto-loading your components directory via your main config file, you can probably just use the class name and/or you could also use [setPathOfAlias](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#setPathOfAlias-detail) and then just use the alias name.